# Extracting data from a live website

Tags: vba

I am a bit new to using VBA to extract data from a website to excel and i was wondering if you guys can help me on extracting data from a website to excel using vba and then make it run every hour?

I can use the code to educate myself on it

Basically, i want to go to the following website

And then just copy paste the travel times for all the roads into excel. This would include Current, Ideal and delay.

Would it be possible to do that?

Comment: Google "VBA automate IE" and experiment with code you find there.  If you have a *specific problem* post back here with your code and a description of what the issue is.  This is not a tutorial site

Answer (score 1):

You will need to add two references in your VBA library to run this code.
To add required references: (VBE > Tools > References)

> *Microsoft HTML Object Library **&** Microsft Internet Controls*

After running this, you will notice that you will need to `Split` the string outputs to isolate the individual variables (current, ideal, delay)  that you want and then you will need to systematically assign these to a table in your excel.

You should do some research on web-scraping to fully understand what is happening. If you navigate to the page > right click on a route > inspect element > you will see the below code is pulling from the tag "tr". `("tr")(3)` will corrospond with the 3rd route detailed on the site.

```
Sub MainSub()
Dim IE As InternetExplorer
Set IE = New InternetExplorer

IE.Navigate "https://www.cp24.com/mobile/commuter-centre/traffic"

Do
    DoEvents
Loop Until IE.ReadyState = ReadyState_Complete

Dim Doc As HTMLDocument
Set Doc = IE.Document

Dim FirstRoute As String
Dim SecondRoute As String

FirstRoute = Trim(Doc.getElementsByTagName("tr")(1).innerText)
SecondRoute = Trim(Doc.getElementsByTagName("tr")(2).innerText)

MsgBox FirstRoute & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & SecondRoute

IE.Quit
Set IE = Nothing
End Sub
```

Comment: Anyway, OP, you got more than your question deserved here. My advice would be to research how you are going to split your “FirstRoute” string to get each output you want. Then try to paste your individual outputs into a table. Once you have that, apply the same logic to every (tr). Last, worry about your hourly update. *baby steps*

Comment: thank you! Just wanted to get a feel about how to go on about doing this. I know you answered more than i deserved so thank you for that

Answer (score 0):

This should do what you want!

```
Option Explicit
Sub Web_Table_Option_One()
    Dim xml    As Object
    Dim html   As Object
    Dim objTable As Object
    Dim result As String
    Dim lRow As Long
    Dim lngTable As Long
    Dim lngRow As Long
    Dim lngCol As Long
    Dim ActRw As Long
    Set xml = CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP.6.0")
    With xml
        .Open "GET", "https://www.cp24.com/mobile/commuter-centre/traffic", False
        .send
    End With
    result = xml.responseText
    Set html = CreateObject("htmlfile")
    html.body.innerHTML = result
    Set objTable = html.getElementsByTagName("Table")
    For lngTable = 0 To objTable.Length - 1
        For lngRow = 0 To objTable(lngTable).Rows.Length - 1
            For lngCol = 0 To objTable(lngTable).Rows(lngRow).Cells.Length - 1
                ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(ActRw + lngRow + 1, lngCol + 1) = objTable(lngTable).Rows(lngRow).Cells(lngCol).innerText
            Next lngCol
        Next lngRow
        ActRw = ActRw + objTable(lngTable).Rows.Length + 1
    Next lngTable
End Sub
```

Set appropriate references...

[image]